# Gsub apostrophe in data frame R

Tags: r, dataframe, gsub, apostrophe

I need to remove all apostrophes from my data frame but as soon as I use....

```
textDataL <- gsub("'","",textDataL)
```

The data frame gets ruined and the new data frame only contains values and NAs, when I am only looking to remove any apostrophes from any text that might be in there? Am I missing something obvious with apostrophes and data frames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep the structure intact:

```
 dat1 <- data.frame(Col1= c("a woman's hat", "the boss's wife", "Mrs. Chang's house", "Mr Cool"),
 Col2= c("the class's hours", "Mr. Jones' golf clubs", "the canvas's size", "Texas' weather"),
 stringsAsFactors=F)
```

I would use

```
     dat1[] <- lapply(dat1, gsub, pattern="'", replacement="")
```

or

```
     library(stringr)
     dat1[] <- lapply(dat1, str_replace_all, "'","")
 dat1
#                Col1                 Col2
# 1      a womans hat     the classs hours
# 2    the bosss wife Mr. Jones golf clubs
# 3 Mrs. Changs house     the canvass size
# 4           Mr Cool        Texas weather
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to apply `gsub` directly on a data frame, but column-wise instead, e.g.

```
apply(textDataL, 2, gsub, pattern = "'", replacement = "")
```

Comment: I would assume the result to be matrix.  If that is the case, gsub("'", "", as.matrix(textDataL) should work.